# noSuchElement exception for same element with same locators in mac, but it works fine in windows

Tags: java, selenium

I have written a simple code and also explicit and implicit wait for it (exact same code in mac & windows) and this code runs fine in windows, but makes no suchElement exception in mac. I tried multiple locator, but mac noSuchElement exception for all of them.

in windows:

```
@Test     
public void testEyeLiner(){         
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 17);         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("site_search_input"))));         WebElement searchInputBox = driver.findElement(By.id("site_search_input"));         searchInputBox.sendKeys("eyeliner");         searchInputBox.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);          wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@data-at='number_of_products']"))));          String searchResults = (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@data-at='number_of_products']"))).getText();         Assert.assertNotEquals(searchResults, "169 Results for “eyeliner”");     } }
```

in mac:

```
@Test
public void testSearch() {
webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 17);
    webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#site_search_input"))));

    WebElement searchInputBox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#site_search_input"));

    searchInputBox.sendKeys("eyeliner");
    searchInputBox.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

    webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@data-at='number_of_products']"))));
    String actualresult = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@data-at='number_of_products']")).getText();

    Assert.assertEquals("result isn't as expected", "169 Results for “eyeliner”", actualresult);
}
```

I tried multiple locators (css selector also), but all of them make noSuchElement exception in mac.